# Twilio for incoming calls how do I detect hang up from caller

Tags: twilio

I have searched the internet but I can not find this.

I have created an application with Python and Flask which accepts incoming calls and redirects to the address where I have defined in webhook. (with ngrok)

```
@app.route("/incomingCall", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def incomingCall():
    ......
    ....

@app.route("/gather", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def gather():

@app.route("/status_callback", methods=['POST'])
def status_callback():
    print("-->/status_callback")
    resp = VoiceResponse()
    resp.redirect('/beginiing')
    return str(resp)
```

If during the call the caller drops the call prematurely how can I detect that?. Right now my app hangs during the gather.

in order to get the status of call I have added this at initialization

```
strTwilio = sid + ":" + token
acTokenTwilio = b64encode(strTwilio.encode()).decode("ascii")

twilioHeaderAcc1 = {'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % acTokenTwilio, 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
payLoad = {"status_callback":myNgrokUrl, "status_callback_event":["completed"]}
twilioStatusCallbackUrl = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/" + "AC......"  # AC... is my account SID
resp = s.post(twilioStatusCallbackUrl, data=json.dumps(payLoad), headers=twilioHeaderAcc1, timeout=15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Status call back URL for the inbound Twilio number your application is using from the Twilio Console.

Comment: Can you please be more specific where and how? An example will help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To get notified of updates to an inbound call, including when a phone call is completed, you should set up a Status Callback URL for your number. You can do this by [editing your number in the dashboard](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/) and setting the field here:

[image]

You can see the [details that are sent to a StatusCallback URL here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#statuscallback).

Comment: Thank you so much this is helpful. I am using python which everything is automated at the initialization including ngrok webhook address. So can you please give me an example code of how I would do this? Say the redirect url for call status is /call_status. For the most part my code works fine in gathering speech and playing DTMF or text to speech. However sometimes when I am in gather mode if the caller hangs up my code hangs. So I want a http req sent to me indicating caller hang up.

Comment: You can [update the status callback for a number by making an update request to the incoming phone numbers resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource#update-an-incomingphonenumber-resource).

Comment: Thanks I tried --> HTTPO Post --> api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC...... where the Post data={'status_callback': 'xxxxx.ngrok.io/status_callback', "status_callback_event":["completed"]} I got statusCode of 200 in my python flask I have an entry --> @app.route("/status_callback", methods=['POST']) def status_callback(): resp = VoiceResponse() print("status_callback resp --> " + str(resp)) resp.redirect('/begining') return str(resp) but when incoming call is triggered I don't see any in hit to this url--> xxxxx.ngrok.io/status_callback

Comment: Two things there. The [Twilio API accepts `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/your-request-to-twilio), not JSON, so you'll need a different HTTP request, I can't see you adding any authentication to that request either. Second thing, responding to a status callback webhook with TwiML won't do anything as status callbacks are asynchronous to the call itself.

Comment: sorry I actually had the header originally to make it simpler to understate I added the code in my original post above please help me verify

Comment: It looks, from the code you’re sharing, that you’re trying to set `status_callback`, however the raw parameters to the API are camel case, so should be `statusCallback`. See how that goes for you.

Answer (score 0):

For context here, the user is setting the voice and status callback URLs via the incoming phone numbers resource. To achieve this, you need to pass the staus callback URL as a parameter. Please see the example below, on how this is done using the Python helper library.

```
incoming_phone_number = client \
    .incoming_phone_numbers('PNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') \
    .update(
            voice_url='https://xxxxxxx.ngrok.io/voice',
            status_callback='https://xxxxxxx.ngrok.io/status_callback' 
     )
```